# image not saving in original resolution

Tags: java, android

This is the code that save image  in very low resolution.The image from url is too big but when I save image through this code it reduce size and resolution of image

```
private void saveImage(final String uri) throws IOException, 
 IllegalStateException {
 URL url = new URL(uri);
 InputStream input = url.openStream();

 File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(storagePath + "/myImage.png");

 try {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
   int bytesRead = 0;
   while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
     output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
 } finally {
   output.close();
 }
```

Comment: You may try to sum up the `bytesRead` and finally print it to check that the read file is really the expected large image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
Bitmap bitmapImage; //your input bitmap to save   

File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(storagePath + "/myImage.png")

try {           
    // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
    bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```